# How to use Swift @autoclosure

Tags: closures, swift

I noticed when writing an `assert` in Swift that the first value is typed as

```
@autoclosure() -> Bool
```

with an overloaded method to return a generic `T` value, to test existence via the `LogicValue` `protocol`.

However sticking strictly to the question at hand. It appears to want an `@autoclosure` that returns a `Bool`.

Writing an actual closure that takes no parameters and returns a Bool does not work, it wants me to call the closure to make it compile, like so:

```
assert({() -> Bool in return false}(), "No user has been set", file: __FILE__, line: __LINE__)
```

However simply passing a Bool works:

```
assert(false, "No user has been set", file: __FILE__, line: __LINE__)
```

So what is going on? What is `@autoclosure`?

**Edit:** `@auto_closure` was renamed `@autoclosure`

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Consider a function that takes one argument, a simple closure that takes no argument:

```
func f(pred: () -> Bool) {
    if pred() {
        print("It's true")
    }
}
```

To call this function, we have to pass in a closure

```
f(pred: {2 > 1})
// "It's true"
```

If we omit the braces, we are passing in an expression and that's an error:

```
f(pred: 2 > 1)
// error: '>' produces 'Bool', not the expected contextual result type '() -> Bool'
```

`@autoclosure` creates an automatic closure around the expression. So when the caller writes an expression like `2 > 1`, it's automatically wrapped into a closure to become `{2 > 1}` before it is passed to `f`. So if we apply this to the function `f`:

```
func f(pred: @autoclosure () -> Bool) {
    if pred() {
        print("It's true")
    }
}

f(pred: 2 > 1)
// It's true
```

So it works with just an expression without the need to wrap it in a closure.

Comment: Actually the last one, doesn't work. It should be `f({2 >1}())`

Comment: @JoelFischer I am seeing the same thing as @JackyBoy. Calling `f(2 > 1)` works. Calling `f({2 > 1})` fails with `error: function produces expected type 'Bool'; did you mean to call it with '()'?`. I tested it in a playground and with the Swift REPL.

Comment: I somehow read the second to last answer as the last answer, I'll have to double check, but it would make sense if it failed, as you are basically putting a closure inside a closure, from what i understand.

Comment: there is a blog post about the reason they did that https://developer.apple.com/swift/blog/?id=4

Comment: Note that as of beta 5 `@auto_closure` has been renamed to `@autoclosure`.

Comment: Two things should also be noted: (1) an `@autoclosure` doesn't accept any arguments; (2) the syntax is convenient for passing function calls, where the body of the function is written separately to the closure

Comment: Great explanation. Note also that in Swift 1.2 'autoclosure' is now an attribute of the parameter declaration, so it's `func f(@autoclosure pred: () -> Bool)`

Comment: As of Swift 3, `@autoclosure` (as well as `@noescape`) is now an attribute of the parameter **type** rather than the parameter name: `func f(pred: @autoclosure () -> Bool)`. See [SE-0049](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0049-noescape-autoclosure-type-attrs.md).

Answer (score 31):

Here's a practical example — my `print` override (this is Swift 3):

```
func print(_ item: @autoclosure () -> Any, separator: String = " ", terminator: String = "\n") {
    #if DEBUG
    Swift.print(item(), separator:separator, terminator: terminator)
    #endif
}
```

When you say `print(myExpensiveFunction())`, my `print` override overshadows Swift's `print` and is called. `myExpensiveFunction()` is thus wrapped in a closure *and not evaluated*. If we're in Release mode, it will *never* be evaluated, because `item()` won't be called. Thus we have a version of `print` that doesn't evaluate its arguments in Release mode.

Comment: I am late to the party, but what is the impact of evaluating `myExpensiveFunction()`?. 
If instead of using autoclosure you pass the function to print like  `print(myExpensiveFunction)`, what would be the impact? Thanks.

Answer (score 11):

Description of auto_closure from the docs:

> You can apply the auto_closure attribute to a function type that has a
>   parameter type of () and that returns the type of an expression (see
>   Type Attributes). An autoclosure function captures an implicit closure
>   over the specified expression, instead of the expression itself. The
>   following example uses the auto_closure attribute in defining a very
>   simple assert function:

And here's the example apple uses along with it.

```
func simpleAssert(condition: @auto_closure () -> Bool, message: String) {
    if !condition() {
        println(message)
    }
}
let testNumber = 5
simpleAssert(testNumber % 2 == 0, "testNumber isn't an even number.")
```

Basically what it means is you pass a boolean expression as that first argument instead of a closure and it automatically creates a closure out of it for you. That's why you can pass false into the method because it is a boolean expression, but can't pass a closure.

Comment: Note that you don't actually need to use `@auto_closure` here. The code works fine without it: `func simpleAssert(condition: Bool, message: String) { if !condition { println(message) } }`. Use `@auto_closure` when you need to evaluate an argument repeatedly (e.g., if you were implementing a `while`-like function) or you need to delay evaluation of an argument (e.g., if you were implementing short-circuiting `&&`).

Comment: @nathan Hi, nathan. Could you please cite me a sample regarding the use of `autoclosure` with a `while`-like function? I don't seem to figure that out. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: @connor You might want to update your answer for Swift 3.

Answer (score 4):

This shows a useful case of `@autoclosure` https://airspeedvelocity.net/2014/06/28/extending-the-swift-language-is-cool-but-be-careful/

> Now, the conditional expression passed as the first parameter to until will be automatically wrapped up into a closure expression and can be called each time around the loop

```
func until<L: LogicValue>(pred: @auto_closure ()->L, block: ()->()) {
    while !pred() {
        block()
    }
}

// doSomething until condition becomes true
until(condition) {
    doSomething()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's just a way to get rid of the curly braces in a closure call, simple example:

```
    let nonAutoClosure = { (arg1: () -> Bool) -> Void in }
    let non = nonAutoClosure( { 2 > 1} )

    let autoClosure = { (arg1: @autoclosure () -> Bool) -> Void in }
    var auto = autoClosure( 2 > 1 ) // notice curly braces omitted
```

Answer (score 0):

**@autoclosure**

`@autoclosure` converts(wraps) expression inside function parameter in a `closure`[<sup>[About]</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60988242/4770877)

Pros:

- easy to read `assert(2 == 5, "failed")`
- curly braces are not used

Cons

- hard to read. When you pass a function inside `@autoclosure` it is not clear that this function will be deferred(because it is closure inside). `fooWithAutoClosure(a: foo0())` - `foo0()` will be called not immediately as we expect reading this line

> Overusing autoclosures can make your code hard to understand. The context and function name should make it clear that evaluation is being deferred.

[Official doc](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Closures.html)

- `@autoclosure` doesn't take any parameters

  ```
  func foo(p: @autoclosure () -> Void)
  ```
- `@autoclosure` accept any function with only appropriate **returned** type

More examples

```
//functions block
func foo0() -> String {
    return "foo0"
}

func foo1(i1: Int) -> String {
    return "foo1 " + String(i1)
}

func foo2(i1: Int, i2: Int) -> String {
    return "foo2 " + String(i1 + i2)
}
```

```
//closures block
func fooWithClosure0(p: () -> String) -> String {
    return "fooWithClosure0 " + p()
}

func fooWithClosure1(p: (Int) -> String) -> String {
    return "fooWithClosure1 " + p(1)
}

func fooWithClosure2(p: (Int, Int) -> String) -> String {
    return "fooWithClosure2 " + p(1, 2)
}
```

```
//@autoclosure
func fooWithAutoClosure(a: @autoclosure () -> String) -> String {
    return "fooWithAutoClosure " + a()
}
```

```
//test closures
func testClosures() {
    XCTAssertEqual("fooWithClosure0 foo0", fooWithClosure0(p: foo0))
    XCTAssertEqual("fooWithClosure1 foo1 1", fooWithClosure1(p: foo1))
    XCTAssertEqual("fooWithClosure2 foo2 3", fooWithClosure2(p: foo2))
    
    XCTAssertEqual("fooWithClosure2 foo2 3", fooWithClosure2(p: { (i1, i2) -> String in
        return "fooWithClosure2 " + "foo2 " + String(i1 + i2)
    }))
}
```

```
//test @autoclosure
func testAutoClosures() {
    XCTAssertEqual("fooWithAutoClosure HelloWorld", fooWithAutoClosure(a: "HelloWorld")) //"HelloWorld" is String as returned value of @autoclosure
    
    XCTAssertEqual("fooWithAutoClosure foo0", fooWithAutoClosure(a: foo0()))
    XCTAssertEqual("fooWithAutoClosure foo1 1", fooWithAutoClosure(a: foo1(i1: 1)))
    XCTAssertEqual("fooWithAutoClosure foo2 3", fooWithAutoClosure(a: foo2(i1: 1, i2: 2)))
}
```