# What is the shortest way to run same code n times in Swift?

Tags: swift

I have a code that I need to run exactly `n` times in Swift. What is the shortest possible syntax for that?

I am currently using the `for` loop but it is a lot of typing.

```
for i in 0..<n { /* do something */ }
```

Is there a shorter/nicer way for running same code `n` times in Swift?

Comment: I would say that is already pretty damn short. How much shorter do you want to go?

Comment: @hexagonstar a want to push Swift to its theoretical limit if it's not reached already here.

Comment: You want to run it infinite times, well try using a `while`

Comment: `for i in 0 ..< n` is already the absolute minimum. You could use a while loop, incrementing a counter but that wouldn't be shorter.

Comment: Note this [spectacular solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32633406/294884) to a similar problem

Comment: Swift will complain if you do not use the `i` so something shorter would be appropriate.

Comment: @Jonny that’s what the `_` is for. `for _ in 0..<n { }`

Comment: @BadmintonCat I want something like Kotlin repeat(n) { }

Answer (score 51, accepted):

Sticking with a `for` loop - you could extend `Int` to conform to `SequenceType` to be able to write:

```
for i in 5 { /* Repeated five times */ }
```

To make `Int` conform to `SequenceType` you'll could do the following:

```
extension Int : SequenceType {
    public func generate() -> RangeGenerator<Int> {
        return (0..<self).generate()
    }
}
```

Comment: It is sick!  A small point, for me "i in 5" would mean i in 12345 rather than i in 01234.  (I'd use a psuedo-keyword more like, perhaps, "upTo" for 01234.)  Of course, opinions would differ on this, but bear it in mind.

Answer (score 96):

Speaking of syntax, you might define your own shortest syntax:

```
extension Int {
    func times(_ f: () -> ()) {
        if self > 0 {
            for _ in 0..<self {
                f()
            }
        }
    }
    
    func times(_ f: @autoclosure () -> ()) {
        if self > 0 {
            for _ in 0..<self {
                f()
            }
        }
    }
}

var s = "a"
3.times {
    s.append(Character("b"))
}
s // "abbb"


var d = 3.0
5.times(d += 1.0)
d // 8.0
```

Comment: `repeat` is a keyword in Swift 2, so you have to choose a different name. – Adding `@escape` and perhaps `throws/rethrows` might also make sense.

Comment: As well as this spectacular answer, be sure to check out [another](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32633406/294884) spectacular solution to a similar problem.

Comment: Why are there two versions of the func, one with and one without @autoclosure?

Comment: @JoeBlow check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24102617/how-to-use-swift-autoclosure

Comment: It is possible to use Swift keywords as function names in Swift. Put a backslash tick before and after the name, as we do here to style text as code: `repeat`.

Comment: Is there any benefit to the `@autoclosure` version, other than stylistic preference? Given that using parentheses or curly braces is the same number of characters and keystrokes either way (e.g. writing `5.times{d += 1.0}` is just as easy), it seems redundant.

Answer (score 43):

You have several ways of doing that:

Using for loops:

```
for i in 1...n { `/*code*/` }
```

```
for i = 0 ; i < n ; i++ { `/*code*/` }
```

```
for i in n { `/*code*/` }
```

using while loops:

```
var i = 0
while (i < n) {
    `/*code*/`
   ` i++`
}
```

```
var i = 0
repeat {
   ` /*code*/`
    `i++`
} while(i <= n)
```

Comment: `for i in n` to work you must use @ABakerSmith's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30560726/2500457

Comment: `for i in 1...n` crashes for n = 0. So if this a valid input, make sure to use one of the other methods.

Comment: the `++` operator was removed from Swift

Answer (score 33):

```
for _ in 1...5 {
  //action will be taken 5 times.
}
```

Answer (score 19):

you could use functional programming on a range instead of a loop, for shorter and "nicer" syntax for example

```
(0..<n).forEach{print("Index: \($0)")}
```

Other answers mention defining your own syntax for that. So - that can be fine for a tiny personal project, or as a learning experience. But defining your own syntax for something so trivial and basic in a large project would be maintenance and readability hell.

Comment: I was trying to do this, but it wasn't working without the parenthesis

Comment: I guess the resulting expression is ambiguous without the brackets

Answer (score 11):

You could do something like this:

```
10⨉{ print("loop") }
```

Using a custom operator and an extension on `Int`:

```
infix operator ⨉ // multiplication sign, not lowercase 'x'

extension Int {
    static func ⨉( count:Int, block: () ->Void  ) {
        (0..<count).forEach { _ in block() }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

ABakerSmith's answer updated for Swift 4:

```
extension Int: Sequence {
    public func makeIterator() -> CountableRange<Int>.Iterator {
        return (0..<self).makeIterator()
    }
}
```

Use:

```
for i in 5 {
    //Performed 5 times
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Shorter and (I think) clearer:

```
for i in 1...n { } // note: this will fail if n < 1
```

or

```
for i in n { }
```

Comment: `for i in 1...n` crashes for n = 0. So if this a valid input, make sure to use one of the other methods.

Comment: Well observed - comment added.

Answer (score 2):

In Swift, what you have is the [shortest syntax](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ControlFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH9-ID121) for performing a loop operation.

> Swift provides two kinds of loop that perform a set of statements a
> certain number of times:
>
> The **for-in** loop performs a set of statements for each item in a
> sequence.
>
> The **for** loop performs a set of statements until a specific
> condition is met.

If you want to run it infinite times, well try using a `while`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of answers here, highlighting just how creative you can be, with Swift.

I needed an array so I did this

```
extension Int {
    func of<T>(iteration: (Int) -> T) -> [T] {
        var collection = [T]()
        for i in 0..<self {
            collection.append(iteration(i))
        }
        return collection
    }
}

fun strings() -> [String] {
    return 4.of { "\($0) teletubby" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for-loops are a common way to repeat code. Here is an example of using a for-loop to hide six outlets, versus writing the same code for six outlets. Plus if you make another outlet all you have to do is add it to the array.

```
let array = [outLet0, outlet1, outlet2, outLet3, outLet4, outLet5]

for outlet in array {
  outlet.hidden = true
}
```

Versus writing it like this:

```
outlet0.hidden = true
outlet1.hidden = true
outlet2.hidden = true
outlet3.hidden = true
outlet4.hidden = true
outlet5.hidden = true
```

Answer (score -1):

Swift is so awesome, just write your own function or extension and you got it ;) 100 of options there, everyone can do it its own way just look at those answers here.

Or better, write it as you already do, as is common when apps are build in team, as everyone would do it differently anyway and all projects need those extension to be written again or own libs to have and maintain just for stupid thing, that you can write just by some standard way, as you already did with your for loop.

Answer (score -2):

**ONLY 5 CHARACTERS (not including n or code)**

```
r(){}
```

If you're just testing things and need a REALLY short line, try this. Emphasis on using this for testing, not in production, because no one will know what is going on without documentation.

**define this somewhere globally**

```
func r(_ n : UInt, _ c: @escaping () -> Void) { for _ in 0..<n { c() } }
```

**call this when you want to run it**

```
r(5) { /*code*/ }
```

Answer (score -4):

The only loop shorter than that is an infinite while loop:

```
while (true) {
}
```

But you would still have to increase a counter and check it in the loop to break the loop, and in the end it wouldn't be shorter.

Comment: You even could shave a few more characters off by doing `for ;; { }` :)