# A SwiftUI View's default memberwise initializer VS custom initializer

Tags: swift, swiftui

In short - when construction a custom SwiftUI View with a ViewModel ("MyView"/"MyViewModel") like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {

    var body: some View {
        MyView(viewModel: MyViewModel())
    }
}
```

Why is this:

```swift
struct MyView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel: MyViewModel

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello world!")
    }
}
```

Not the same as this:

```swift
struct MyView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel: MyViewModel

    init(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
        self._viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel)
    }

    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello world!")
    }
}
```

When debugging, it looks like the second option causes new instances of `MyViewModel` to be created every time `MyView` is reconstructed by SwiftUI. But in the first option, the StateObject wrapper seems to do its job, and makes sure only one instance of `MyViewModel` is created for all reconstructions of `MyView`.

Is there some extra SwiftUI magic applied to using the View's default memberwise initializer VS a custom one? Perhaps by the ViewBuilder?

Below is a simple example app, MyApp.swift, to see the behaviour in action.

```swift
//
//  MyApp.swift
//

import SwiftUI

@main
struct MyApp: App {

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @AppStorage("redBackground") private var redBackground: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Flipping "redBackground" will cause a reconstruction of the view hierarchy
            if redBackground {
                Color.red
            } else {
                Color.green
            }
            MyView(viewModel: MyViewModel())
        }
    }
}

final class MyViewModel: ObservableObject {

    init() {
        print("MyViewModel.init")
    }
}

struct MyView: View {

    @StateObject var viewModel: MyViewModel

    @AppStorage("redBackground") private var redBackground: Bool = false

    // WARNING: Uncommenting this causes the view model to be recreated every reconstruction of the view!
    //    init(viewModel: MyViewModel) {
    //        self._viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel)
    //    }

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Toggle background") {
                redBackground = !redBackground
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't use view model objects, in SwiftUI the `View` struct is already the model that is used to create/update the actual UIViews.

Comment: Disagree with the above.  The SwiftUI view should handle generating/updating the view and presenting the data.  That should be its single responsibility.  Keep managing the data separate from it as much as possible and a view model is fine for this. ( Ignoring the fact that the 'View" is a protocol, not a struct, as a slip).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Notice that the [`StateObject.init(wrappedValue:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject/init(wrappedvalue:)) initialiser takes an [*autoclosure*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24102617/5133585).

```
init(wrappedValue thunk: @autoclosure @escaping () -> ObjectType)
```

This `@autoclosure` is propagated to the auto-generated memberwise initialiser of `MyView`, making the expression `MyViewModel()` you passed to the view lazily evaluated. This is what causes SwiftUI to only create one view model for all redraws of the view.

I can't find any documentation documenting this propagation of `@autoclosure`, but I can confirm it happens with this code:

```
@propertyWrapper
struct MyStateObject {
    var wrappedValue: String
    
    init(wrappedValue: @autoclosure () -> String) {
        self.wrappedValue = wrappedValue()
    }
}

struct MyView {
    @MyStateObject var foo: String
}
```

When you compile it, there is a symbol in the binary named `MyView.init(foo: @autoclosure () -> Swift.String) -> MyView`. See [godbolt.org](https://godbolt.org/z/n3dTEsW93)

On the other hand, your handwritten initialiser does not take `@autoclosure`, so `MyViewModel()` is eagerly evaluated. The lazy expression you pass into `StateObject.init(wrappedValue:)` now is just the parameter name `viewModel`, which is not a complicated thing to evaluate :)

So to recreate the same behaviour with your own handwritten initialiser, you should add `@autoclosure` too:

```
init(viewModel: @autoclosure @escaping () -> MyViewModel) {
    self._viewModel = StateObject(wrappedValue: viewModel())
}
```

Comment: Ahh! So that's the magic going on! Well that explains it then Thanks a lot for the super nice writeup/explanation! 